# sparql is there any way to make simplify this query

Tags: sparql

I build a query, it is very simple, but my problem is that i find myself repeating the same triples again and again.

I have a class called `TemporalContext`, each instance of it has:

**Either** the property `canBeRecommendedFrom`, (range datetime)

**or** the property `canBeRecommendedUntil` (range datetime)

**or both**

Each instance **could** have as well:

**Either** the property `weightIfContextMatched`

**or** the property `weightIfContextDoesNotMatch`

**or both**

What I want to do is:

1. If an instance of `TemporalContext` has both `canBeRecommendedFrom` and `canBeRecommendedUtill`, then if it today is inside that range, select the value of `weightIfContextMatched`, if not, select the value of `weightIfontextDoesNotFound`. However, maybe the values `weightIfContextMatched` and `weightIfContextDoesNotMatch` are not set, so then I use a default value.
2. the same thing if the instance of `TemporalContext` has just `canBeRecommendFrom` and doesn't have `canBeRecommendUntil`
3. The same thing is the instance of `TemporalContext` has just `canBeRecommendedUntill` and doesn't have `canBeRecommendFrom`

I did a query for the case in which the instance of `TemporalContext` has both `canBeRecommendedFrom` and `canBeRecommendedUntil` with all the variation of `weightIfContextMatched` and `weightIfContextDoesNotMatch`

Here you go the query

```
select ?item ?finalTemporalWeight where
{
  values ?user {bo:ania} 
  #the items that have temporal context(s)
  {
    select ?item (SUM(?temporalWeight) as ?finalTemporalWeight) {
   ?item a rs:RecommendableClass .
      #to be sure that the item belongs to the class
      filter exists {
        ?item a ?itemClass
      }

  #the items that has both from and until temporal context
  {

    {
      #this block is if today is inside the range
      ?tempoalContext a rs:TemporalContext .
      ?tempoalContext rs:appliedOnItems ?itemClass .
      #to be sure that both until and from were set.
      ?tempoalContext rs:canBeRecommendedFrom ?fromLimit .
      ?tempoalContext rs:canBeRecommendedUntil ?untilLimit .



      #check if today is before the until limit
      filter (now () < ?untilLimit)

      #check if today is after the from limit
      filter (now () > ?fromLimit)

     optional
    {
      ?tempoalContext rs:hasWeightIfContextMatched ?weight
    }
    bind((if(bound(?weight), ?weight, 1)) as ?temporalWeight)
    }
    union
    {
      #this block is if today is after the until limit
      ?tempoalContext a rs:TemporalContext .
    ?tempoalContext rs:appliedOnItems ?itemClass .
          #to be sure that both until and from were set.
    ?tempoalContext rs:canBeRecommendedFrom ?fromLimit .
      ?tempoalContext rs:canBeRecommendedUntil ?untilLimit .



       #check if today is after the until limit
    filter (now () > ?untilLimit)

    optional
    {
     ?tempoalContext rs:hasWeightIfContextDoesNotMatch ?weight
    }
    bind((if(bound(?weight), ?weight, 0.1)) as ?temporalWeight)
    }
    union
    {
      #this block is if today is before the from limit
     ?tempoalContext a rs:TemporalContext .
    ?tempoalContext rs:appliedOnItems ?itemClass .
          #to be sure that both until and from were set.
    ?tempoalContext rs:canBeRecommendedFrom ?fromLimit .
      ?tempoalContext rs:canBeRecommendedUntil ?untilLimit .



       #check if today is before the from limit
    filter (now () < ?fromLimit)

    optional
    {
      ?tempoalContext rs:hasWeightIfContextDoesNotMatch ?weight
    }
    bind((if(bound(?weight), ?weight, 0.3)) as ?temporalWeight)

    }

  }
  union
  #the items that has just from temporal context
  {

    {
    #this block is if today is before the from limit
      ?tempoalContext a rs:TemporalContext .
      ?tempoalContext rs:appliedOnItems ?itemClass .
      #to be sure that the from limit is set.
      ?tempoalContext rs:canBeRecommendedFrom ?fromLimit .



      #to be sure that the until limit is not set.
      filter not exists {
        ?tempoalContext rs:canBeRecommendedUntil ?untilLimit .
      }
      #check if today is before the from limit
      filter (now () < ?fromLimit)

     optional
    {
      ?tempoalContext rs:hasWeightIfContextDoesNotMatch ?weight
    }
    bind((if(bound(?weight), ?weight, 0.15)) as ?temporalWeight)

    }
    union
    {
      #this block is if today is after the from limit
      ?tempoalContext a rs:TemporalContext .
      ?tempoalContext rs:appliedOnItems ?itemClass .
      #to be sure that the from limit is set.
      ?tempoalContext rs:canBeRecommendedFrom ?fromLimit .



      #to be sure that the until limit is not set.
      filter not exists {
        ?tempoalContext rs:canBeRecommendedUntil ?untilLimit .
      }
      #check if today is before the from limit
      filter (now () > ?fromLimit)

     optional
    {
      ?tempoalContext rs:hasWeightIfContextMatched ?weight
    }
    bind((if(bound(?weight), ?weight, 0.25)) as ?temporalWeight)
    }
  }
  union
  #the items that has just until temporal context
  {
     {
    #this block is if today is before the until limit
      ?tempoalContext a rs:TemporalContext .
      ?tempoalContext rs:appliedOnItems ?itemClass .
      #to be sure that the until limit is set.

      ?tempoalContext rs:canBeRecommendedUntil ?untilLimit .
      #to be sure that the from limit is not set.



      filter not exists {
        ?tempoalContext rs:canBeRecommendedFrom ?fromLimit .
      }
      #check if today is before the until limit
      filter (now () < ?untilLimit)

     optional
    {
      ?tempoalContext rs:hasWeightIfContextMatched ?weight
    }
    bind((if(bound(?weight), ?weight, 0.35)) as ?temporalWeight)

    }
    union
    {
      #this block is if today is after the until limit
      ?tempoalContext a rs:TemporalContext .
      ?tempoalContext rs:appliedOnItems ?itemClass .
      #to be sure that the until limit is set.
      ?tempoalContext rs:canBeRecommendedUntil ?untilLimit .


      #to be sure that the from limit is not set.
      filter not exists {
        ?tempoalContext rs:canBeRecommendedFrom ?fromLimit .
      }
      #check if today is after the until limit
      filter (now () > ?untilLimit)

     optional
    {
      ?tempoalContext rs:hasWeightIfContextDoesNotMatch ?weight
    }
    bind((if(bound(?weight), ?weight, 0.45)) as ?temporalWeight)
    }
  }


      union
      #the items that have temporal context, but that temporal context has no canBeRecommendedFrom nor canBeRecommendedUntil
      {
    select distinct ?item ?temporalWeight {
      ?item a rs:RecommendableClass .
        ?tempoalContext a rs:TemporalContext .
      ?tempoalContext rs:appliedOnItems ?itemClass .
       ?item a ?itemClass .

        #to be sure that neight canBeRecommendFrom nor canBeRecommendedUntil is set
      filter not exists {
        ?tempoalContext rs:canBeRecommendedFrom ?fromLimit .
      }
        filter not exists {
                 ?tempoalContext rs:canBeRecommendedUntil ?untilLimit .
        }
        bind (4.4 as ?temporalWeight)
      }
} 

  }group by ?item
  }
  union
  #the items that don't have a temporal context, we will use the defalut value:
  {
    select distinct ?item ?finalTemporalWeight {
  ?item a rs:RecommendableClass .
    ?tempoalContext a rs:TemporalContext .
     ?tempoalContext rs:appliedOnItems ?itemClass .
    filter not exists {
    ?item a ?itemClass
    }
    bind (2.3 as ?finalTemporalWeight)
  }
  }

}
order by ?item
```

the query is so easy but long, and i find myself repeating the same thing inside each union. and now i have to reapeat the same thing for the second and third case,

I thought before continuing in this long-but-easy-query i ask you first maybe you know a better way to reduce the size of it.

**the query is working very well, i tested it**

#### Update 1

After the appreciate reply from [@Joshua Taylor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1281433/joshua-taylor) here is the result:

[image]

However, this is the result of my code:
[image]

You can see that the row number 6, the item doesn't have any value, the case of that item is: it is before the from limit. so the correct union is `#this block is if today is before the from limit`. but there is no value for `hasWeightIfContextDoenNotMatch` so we should use the default value, which is `0.3`, my code does that, my the code in the answer doesn't.

#### Update 2

Now I finished (and updated the query) developing the boring-so-so-so boring query but i handled all the scenarios, I will tell you the scenarios:

1. The item belongs to a temporalContext class:

1.1. the temporalClass has both canBeRecommendFrom and canBeRecommendUntill

1.1.1. the item is inside the range

1.1.1.1. the weightIfContextMatched exists.

1.1.1.2. the weightIfContextMatched doesn't exist.

1.1.2. the item is before the from limit.

1.1.2.1 the weightIfContextDoesNotMatch exists.

1.1.2.2. the weightIfContextDoesNotMatch doesn't exist.

1.1.3. the item is after the until limit.

1.1.3.1 the weightIfContextDoesNotMatch exists.

1.1.3.2. the weightIfContextDoesNotMatch doesn't exist.

1.2. the temporalClass has just canBeRecommendFrom

1.2.1 the item is after the from limit

1.2.1.1. the weightIfContextMatched exists.

1.2.1.2. the weightIfContextMatched doesn't exist.

1.2.2 the item is before the from limit

1.2.2.1 the weightIfContextDoesNotMatch exists.

1.2.2.2. the weightIfContextDoesNotMatch doesn't exist.

1.3. the temporalClass has just canBeRecommednFrom

1.3.1 the item is before the from limit

1.3.1.1 the weightIfContextDoesNotMatch exists.

1.3.1.2. the weightIfContextDoesNotMatch doesn't exist.

1.3.2 the item is after the from limit

1.3.2.1. the weightIfContextMatched exists.

1.3.2.2. the weightIfContextMatched doesn't exist.

1.4. the temporalClass has neither canBeRecommendFrom nor canBeRecommendUntil

use default value (be careful of duplicated)

2. the item doesn't belong to a temporalClass

use default value (be careful of duplicated)

Comment: It's funny to see what you consider as being a 'simple' resp. 'easy' query. A lots of triple patterns, VALUES, OPTIONAL, UNION, BIND, FILTER, IF-ELSE, ...

Comment: Two simple but not really helpful transformations: 1) correct spelling of variable `tempoalContext` 2) use TURTLE syntax features

Comment: @AniaDavid Also check that you weren't using the query from [this older version of my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36485599/3) where I actually mentioned that there was a case where ?temporalWeight wouldn't get a value.  Be sure to use the query from the latest version of my answer.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor okay now it is working, but not for all the cases, you covered the ones that i showed you in the first version of my questions, i just updated my question to show the ultimate final scenarios (i hope you don't hate me after this update). could you have a look please? they are all pretty similar, but just the cases `1.4` and `2` are a little bit different because we need to be careful of duplicated (again i am so sorry for this long query)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor kindly if you want a real data to test, i can give you, just let me know, now i must take a 20 minutes break after listing all the scenarios, i feel my head rounding :)

Comment: @AniaDavid I answered the question as it was written, and I think that the approach I provided should be the guidance that you'd need to cover more cases.  By updating the question in the way you have (the first updates were useful clarifications, but the second is just making it a **different** question), you're making it a moving target.  Have a look at [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253762/1281433) for some comments about that kind of practice.

Comment: The last update adds a whole lot to the question.  I expect that you can simplfy it just like we simplified the query.  Look for common conditions, bring them to the front, then figure out the minimal stuff needed in order to separate the different cases.   This question has grown enough, that I don't think I'll be spending much more time on it for free. I'd be happy to discuss consulting rates if you'd like.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Okay I got the idea, thank you

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor i don't know if this is considered as a part of this question of not, kindly let me know if it is not. your approach gives values like `3.76` while the original (long) query gives `3.76000002`, is that normal please ?

Comment: @AniaDavid I don't know what datatype you use to represent weights in your data, but it's certainly possible that there could be different datatypes in use.  If you work with floats, you'll get the imprecise values like "3.76000002", whereas (I think) with decimals, you'll get exact values like "3.76".  But it could also be a printing artifact, I suppose?  What happens in your original query if you use 1.0 instead of 1 for the first "default" weight?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor actually there is no `1` or `1.0` at all anymore, because i made all default values zero like this `0`, the data type of the weights in the ontology is float, and in both queries (the original and the smaller) read from the same ontology (the same rdf triples i mean)

Comment: You made them 0 or 0.0?

Comment: i tried both of them (0 ad 0.0) in both queries, the long query always gives 3.76000002 while the small query always 3.76

Comment: maybe another bug by fuseki when using bind and coalesce

Comment: @ania it's possible, but jena is fairly well tested.  I expect it's more something about the numeric types being used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're always looking for a temporal context that is a **TemporalContext**, that is applied on an item class, and that has a from and until limit, so that can come out of the query.  Then you're interested in optional weights to use depending on whether **now()** before, during, or after the interval.  Then you want to set temporal weight as the matching weight (or 1) if we're in the interval, or else the unmatched weight (or 0.1) if we're after it, or else the unmatched weight (or 0.3) if we're before it.  I'd do that with a **bind** that checks those conditions, and uses **coalesce** to select the optional value or the default:

```sql
SELECT  ?item ?temporalContext ?itemClass ?weight ?temporalWeight
WHERE
  { VALUES ?user { bo:ania }
    ?item a rs:RecommendableClass .

    ?temporalContext a rs:TemporalContext ;
      rs:appliedOnItems ?itemClass ;
      rs:canBeRecommendedFrom ?fromLimit ;
      rs:canBeRecommendedUntil ?untilLimit .

      OPTIONAL {
         ?temporalContext rs:hasWeightIfContextMatched ?matchedWeight
      }
      OPTIONAL {
        ?temporalContext rs:hasWeightIfContextDoesNotMatch ?unmatchedWeight
      }

      bind(if(now() < ?fromLimit,
              coalesce(?unmatchedWeight, 0.1),
              if(?fromLimit <= now() && now() <= ?untilLimit,
                 coalesce(?matchedWeight, 1.0),
                 if(?untilLimit < now(),
                    coalesce(?unmatchedWeight, 0.3),
                    0.0)))                           #-- default here?
           as ?temporalWeight)
  }
ORDER BY ?item
```

I've used **<=** in checking whether **now()** is *in* the duration, since before if **now()** had been exactly equal to one of them, you might not have caught it.  It it possible that you get to the "default here?" line, though?  I think it's still possible if the data doesn't actually have comparable times there.  as I see it, you can either use a default value there (like 0.0), or you can just assume that if the first two cases didn't match, then you just want the third, in which case you can skip the check altogether and just do:

```sql
  bind(if(now() < ?fromLimit,
          coalesce(?unmatchedWeight, 0.1),
          if(?fromLimit <= now() && now() <= ?untilLimit,
             coalesce(?matchedWeight, 1.0),
             coalesce(?unmatchedWeight, 0.3)))
      as ?temporalWeight)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just to be sure, you've handled the three possible senarios, (with canBeRecommendedFrom and canBeRecommendedUntil, just canBeRecommededFrom, and just canBeRecommendedUntil) right? now it's time to sleep, I will continue tomorrow and test the query and update you. thank you very much

Comment: Hello, i checked your code, we may need to consider the default value, i updated the question to show you the result of your code. could you check please?

Comment: Hello again, I just updated the question again because I finished my code to handle the whole possible senarios, and the code is 100% work but as you see, it is so long and has so many duplicated.